# Asp.Net Core - Enable HttpCompression in Shared Hosting Environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I'm using a shared host running a ASP.Net Core 2.0 web app. When I run the app on localhost, I can see HttpCompression is working just fine (content-encoding: gzip) response header is returned for JS files).

After I deploy to the shared host, the content-encoding: gzip response is no longer there. I tried adding various httpCompression/urlCompression settings in the web.config, but the hosting company says these settings are disabled for my plan.

Is there any other way to make Gzip compression work, or do I have to use a hosting plan where it is enabled in IIS?

**Edit:** I'm also using the ResponseCompression middleware as part of ASP.Net Core and the content-encoding response headers still do not appear. Configure code is as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

...
}

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=604800");
            }
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
              );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttps();

        app.UseRewriter(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Response Compression Middleware; add a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression or Microsoft.AspNetCore.All NuGet package.
See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Set it up via:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddResponseCompression();
    })
    .Configure(app =>
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        // ...
    })
    .Build();
```

**Edit:** In a comment below you mention that your website is on https which is the reason why response compression is off by default to prevent CRIME and BREACH attacks.
You can re-enable this via the EnableForHttps option.

```
services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
options.EnableForHttps = true;
options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});
```

Comment: I'm actually already using this, and the gzip response header still doesn't appear.

Comment: Ensure that the IIS static file handler isn't serving the files instead of this middleware.
Via IIS Manager
1. Navigate to the Modules feature.
2. Select StaticFileModule in the list.
3. Click Remove in the Actions sidebar.

Comment: According to the docs, the StaticFileModule isn't even used/available for ASP.Net Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/modules?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: The document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x mentions: if the IIS static file handler is enabled and the ASP.NET Core Module is configured incorrectly, static files are served. This happens, for example, if the web.config file isn't deployed.

Comment: Can you share some more info, like the order of registration of the middlewares in use, whether the website is on https or behind a reverse proxy, etc.?

Comment: Added Configure code to the post. Yes, the site uses HTTPS for everything.

Comment: Compressed responses over secure connections are disabled by default, but can be controlled via the EnableForHttps option; see The 'Compression with secure protocol' section on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x.

Comment: I just found this at the same time, tried it and it worked. Doh! What a dumb thing I missed. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Updated the answer with the info reflected from these comments.

Comment: I have one question. Does Compression and decompression of file take times?

Comment: @DiwasPoudel Nothing is free in this world; that's why the linked [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2) mentions to let it preferably be handled by the webserver (IIS, Apache) instead of via custom code.